# TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dataframe (df) that looks like:

```
date                 A
2001-01-02      1.0022
2001-01-03      1.1033
2001-01-04      1.1496
2001-01-05      1.1033

2015-03-30    126.3700
2015-03-31    124.4300
2015-04-01    124.2500
2015-04-02    124.8900
```

For the entire time-series I'm trying to divide today's value by yesterdays and log the result using the following:

```
df["B"] = math.log(df["A"] / df["A"].shift(1))
```

However I get the following error:

```
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
```

How can I fix this? I've tried to cast as float using:

```
df["B"] .astype(float)
```

But can't get anything to work.

Comment: Check if there are any non float values like empty strings or strings with something other than numbers

Comment: `math.log` expects a single float value. It doesn't work on pandas Series objects.

Comment: can you try to convert just a small portion of the data to float and see if that works

Comment: why not df["B"] = (df["A"] / df["A"].shift(1)).apply(lambda x: math.log(x))?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can use numpy.log instead. Math.log is expecting a single number, not array.

Answer (score 26):

You can use lambda operator to apply your functions to the pandas data frame or to the series. More specifically if you want to convert each element on a column to a floating point number, you should do it like this:

```
df['A'].apply(lambda x: float(x))
```

here the lambda operator will take the values on that column (as x) and return them back as a float value.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your answer. Your solution worked for me.

Comment: Suppose you want to ONLY consider cases when `x` is numeric? How do you fit this in the lambda?

Answer (score 4):

If you just write `df["A"].astype(float)` you will not change `df`. You would need to assign the output of the `astype` method call to something else, including to the existing series using `df['A'] = df['A'].astype(float)`. Also you might want to either use numpy as @user3582076 suggests, or use [`.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) on the Series that results from dividing today's value by yesterday's.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, for me the answer was to look at the cause of why I had series in the first place.  After looking for a long time about how to change the series into the different assigned data type, I realised that I had defined the same column name twice in the dataframe and that was why I had a series.

Removing the accidental duplication of column name removes this issue :)

Comment: This was what happened in my case as well - my dataframe was modified twice to add columns with the same names by a function, once on the whole df and once on a subset view. Adding a copy() fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Pandas data frame doesn't allow direct use of arithmetic operations on series. you can work around this issue by using FOR Loops in python.

I have done a code example below.

```
import math

df['B'] = ""
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    df_index = df.loc[i]
    results = math.log(df_index['A'] / df_index['A'])
    df['B'] = results

print(df)
```

Comment: Doesn't this assign the same value to all of df['B']?

Answer (score 0):

I used in a different way but it is same as @cemosambora

`(df.A).apply(lambda x: float(x))`
Here, `df` is the pandas dataframe and `A` is a column name