# Logarithm calculation in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to perform a logarithm in series, but I get the following error.

> TypeError: cannot convert the series to class 'float'

I have a dataframe with two column A and B

```
A    B
------
1    5
2    6
3    7
```

I am trying the following:

```
O/p = 10*math.log(10,df['A']+df['B'])
```

Required output:

```
row1 = 10*math.log(10,6)
row2 = 10*math.log(10,8)
row3 = 10*math.log(10,10)
```

But getting TypeError: cannot convert the series to class 'float'

Comment: can you please paste the code instead of an image,

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include 
the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code  necessary 
to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem 
statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and 
Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42988348/typeerror-cannot-convert-the-series-to-class-float). "Math.log is expecting a single number, not array."

Comment: I replaced the image with the text that was on it. It cost me some time to do it. In the future, please consider placing text in your questions, not images of text.

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience,next time i will take care to copy text ,instead of image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`math.log` is meant to work with a `scalar` of type `float`. To compute `log10` of a dataframe column, which is of type series, use `numpy.log10` documented [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.log10.html#numpy.log10).

Example:

```
import numpy 
10*numpy.log10(df['A']+df['B'])
```

Here's a reproducible example:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np 
>>> 
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1,5],[2,6],[3,7]], columns=["A","B"])
>>> df
   A  B
0  1  5
1  2  6
2  3  7
>>> np.log10(df["A"]+df["B"]) 
0    0.778151
1    0.903090
2    1.000000
dtype: float64
>>>
```