# TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'> while using multiprocessing.Pool and dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, type-conversion, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to use multiprocessing.pool.Pool() to parallelize a function that involves selecting data with conditions from an hdf5 file. Here are the relevant functions that I am using

```
def get_data(ra_dec):# function for getting data corresponding to a given grid point
    r = ra_dec[0].apply(lambda x: float(x))
    d = ra_dec[1].apply(lambda x: float(x))
    wh = 'dec < %0.3f and dec > %0.3f and ra < %0.3f and ra > %0.3f' %(d+0.005, d-0.005, r+0.005, r-0.005)
    df_val = hdf1.select('data', where=wh)
    return (df_val)

def parallelize_dataframe(df, func, n_cores=4):
    df = np.radians(df)
    df_split = np.array_split(df, n_cores)
    pool = Pool(n_cores)
    df = pd.concat(pool.map(func, df_split))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return df

parallelize_dataframe(ra_dec_arr,get_data)
```

Here, ra_dec is a dataframe containing coordinate points which are included in the hdf5 file hdf1. The data corresponding to each coordinate needs to be retrieved. "wh" is the condition I use to match the float numbers.
But I am faced with the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "<ipython-input-76-7dfce4b7e5b3>", line 5, in get_data
    wh = 'dec < %0.3f and dec > %0.3f and ra < %0.3f and ra > %0.3f' %(d+0.005, d-0.005, r+0.005, r-0.005)
  File "/home/hp/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 93, in wrapper
    "{0}".format(str(converter)))
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
```

I have tried converting the dataframes to float using the lambda function (as above) with no improvement. Please suggest how I could change my code to resolve this.

Comment: 1) Does the issue show up if you don't use multiprocessing? 2) What is the type of the variables you're converting to float?

Comment: No, it works fine when multiprocessing is not used. I am using the lambda function to convert the coordinate values (floats) in the dataframe ra_dec to float following the suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42988348/typeerror-cannot-convert-the-series-to-class-float . The same error occurs without the lambda conversion too.