# Rounding up pandas column to nearest n unit value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a 200000 row dataframe that looks like this
df =

| index | name | d2b(m) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Jon | 199.9 |
| 1 | Amy | 29 |
| 2 | Fyn | 19 |
| 3 | Luc | 30 |
| 4 | And | 76 |
| 5 | Pia | 90 |

I am writing a function to classify the "distance to bus stop (d2b)" column into a new column for every 10 meters, expecting:

| index | name | d2b (m) | class (<= x meters) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Jon | 199.9 | 200m |
| 1 | Amy | 29 | 30m |
| 2 | Fyn | 19 | 20m |
| 3 | Luc | 33 | 40m |
| 4 | And | 76 | 80m |
| 5 | Pia | 90 | 90m |

Code that works (updated):

```
numpy.ceil(data["d2b (m)"]/10)*10
```

Comment: what would be the expected value in your new column if d2b was 33?

Comment: @EmiOB  d2b 33 results in new column 40

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way of achieving this:

```
   import math
   df['class (<= x meters)'] = math.ceil(df[d2b(m)]/10)*10
```

Comment: what if I want to classify every 20 meters? thank you

Comment: `df['class (<= x meters)'] = math.ceil(df[d2b(m)]/20)*20`. If this helps, please consider marking this answer as correct.

Comment: it results to "TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'> "

Comment: d2b column probably contains non-numeric values

Comment: using `numply.ceil` could fix the error encountered above from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42988348/typeerror-cannot-convert-the-series-to-class-float